# Iframe height not displaying correctly in Firefox only

Tags: css, firefox, iframe, height, firebug

I have created a page that has similar functionality to that of the DiggBar (i.e. a header of specified `height` and an `iframe` below filling the rest of the page).

I had this working a while back with desired results, but all of a sudden the `height` of the `iframe` has gone from `100%` of the remaining page `height` to only `44.8px`.  The catch is that this is only occurring in one browser — Firefox on Ubuntu.

I thought that this should be happening in all other browsers, but it's not.  It displays correctly in IE, FF, & Chrome on Windows and Chrome on Ubuntu.

Finally, using Firebug, I have selected `inspect element` to try to determine what's going on, but it only tells me that my `height` is defined to be `100%`, but that it is *computed* to be only `44.8px`.

I am looking for some guidance as to how best to debug this issue because I have completely run out of ideas.  I didn't think that it would be necessary to post all of the code that produces this problem, but if any is absolutely needed, just ask.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the height of the immediate parent that contains the `iframe`?

Comment: @BryanDowning the `iframe`'s parent is defined to be `100%` - Firebug says that computes to `454px`

Comment: Are you able to manually set the `height` of the `iframe` to something like 200px? How tall is the `iframe` supposed to be in pixels (I know it should be dynamic depending on the browser size, just give me what it should be in your window right now)? Does the parent look like it is actually `454px` tall? If you replace the `iframe` with a `div` and apply the same style rules, does it act the same?

Comment: @BryanDowning Yes, I am able to manually set the `height` of the `ifame`.  The `454px` is the desired height of the `iframe` and yes, the parent is filling this portion correctly.  If I replace the `iframe` with a `div`, I receive the same problem (`height` of `div` not filling parent) - works in all other browsers, just not this FF install.

Comment: Without being able to see it, I'm basically out of ideas. You don't have any weird floats or padding going on do you? You could fix it with javascript by getting the height of the parent and dynamically setting the height of the iframe on resize, but that's lame...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the *Cascading* part of the Cascading Style Sheets threw me off.  I had another (let's call it 'hidden') reference to the parent of the `iframe` which caused the weird `height` calculation issue.

Funny that this only happened in my Ubuntu version of Firefox, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a complicated layout structure, setting height of all divs to 100% may break the page layout. In this case I recommend using javascript to set the height of iframe to 100%. In my case I used JQuery, but I believe pure javascript DOM functions should also work. I set the height of iframe equal to parent div height:

```
$('#doc-preview iframe').height($('#doc-preview').height());
```

Here the doc-preview is an id of iframe's parent div.

Make sure to run this script after the page has been loaded.